# AWS Python Lambda with multiple functions

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, loops, boto3

I have an AWS Lambda function in python3.7. The way its set up im running the `lambda_handler(event, context)` function and passing data to a separate function that calls itself multiple times depending on what is passed into it. How do I then return data from the second function?

```
import json
import boto3

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # code to get initial data
    x = second_function(data)
    print(x)
    return x



def second_function(data):
    # code to manipulate data
    if condition:
       print(newData)
       second_function(newData)
    else:
       return allData
```

I expected this to return allData back through the `lambda_handler` function, but instead returns null

And logged is

```
newData
newData
newData
None
```

I am using the second function to get data based on the last `PaginationToken`. Is there a better way to get paginated data rather than creating a second recursive function?

Comment: Your `second_function()` doesn't seem to return anything if `condition` is true. And if `condition` is false, it appears that `allData` is empty (`None`).

Comment: if condition is true the second_function calls itself and sends what it has already gotten. If the condition is false (when it reaches the final page) it is supposed to return all the data combined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to use a **boto3 paginator**.

Alternatively, you could use a **loop** rather than a **recursive function**.

It would be something like:

```
response = api_call()
<do stuff with response>
while response['NextToken']:
    response=api_call(NextToken=response['NextToken'])
    <do stuff with response>
```

You can probably avoid having to double-up the `<do stuff>` bit by improving on the `while` statement.

Comment: Thanks! I'm fairly new to python and didn't think to use a while statement